# Powershell remote returning false positive on IIS:\AppPools lookup

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-remoting

Whatever value entered for $appPoolName always returns true for Test-Path when sent to the remote machine, even when no such pool exists.  When run locally in powershell on those machines, the proper result is returned.  PSRemote is verified to be enabled on the target machines.

```
$appPoolName = 'Abc123'
$scriptBlock = {
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    if (Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName) {
        Write-Host "Already installed."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Installing..."
        $appPool = New-Item –Path IIS:\AppPools\$using:appPoolName
        $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name managedRuntimeVersion -Value 'v4.0'
    }
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName LT-CODE8 -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Why is this reporting true, or what steps can I take to further diagnose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the $using: on the first call of $appPoolname:

```
if (Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\$using:appPoolName) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably enabling cred-ssp is needed on the remote machine. Please see this thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/3ea1ac5a-60f4-4ba1-9bdf-1119e2e5c896/testpath-fails-on-remote-computer-with-invokecommand?forum=ITCG

Comment: Test-Path will fail only if it requires a second hop. But IIS:\ is a PSDrive on the machine that the user is connecting to, so no second hop is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was running Powershell in VS Code. In ISE it always worked as expected.